# How to add subtitles from a SRT file on a video and play it with Gstreamer in a c program

Tags: c, video, gstreamer, subtitle

I want to play a video with a C program using Gstreamer and adding subtitles from a SRT file.

I'm new to gstreamer and I somehow figured out who to make it work in command-line :

```
gst-launch filesrc location=video.srt ! subparse ! \
    overlay. filesrc location=video.ogv ! oggdemux name=demux \
    demux. ! queue ! vorbisdec ! audioconvert ! autoaudiosink \
    demux. ! queue ! theoradec ! ffmpegcolorspace ! subtitleoverlay name=overlay ! autovideosink;
```

The problem is that I can play the video from a C program but I didn't understood how to add the subtitles.

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    GMainLoop *loop;

    GstElement *pipeline, *source, *demuxer, *audioDecoder, *videoDecoder, *audioConv, *videoConv, *videosink, 
            *audiosink, *audioQueue, *videoQueue;
    GstBus *bus;

    gst_init (&argc, &argv);

    loop = g_main_loop_new (NULL, FALSE);

    if (argc < 2 && argc > 3) {
        g_printerr ("Usage: %s <Ogg/Vorbis filename> [Srt filename]\n", argv[0]);
        return -1;
    }

    pipeline     = gst_pipeline_new ("audiovideo-player");
    source       = gst_element_factory_make ("filesrc",          "file-source");
    demuxer      = gst_element_factory_make ("oggdemux",         "ogg-demuxer");
    audioQueue   = gst_element_factory_make ("queue",            "audio-queue");
    videoQueue   = gst_element_factory_make ("queue",            "video-queue");
    audioDecoder = gst_element_factory_make ("vorbisdec",        "vorbis-decoder");
    videoDecoder = gst_element_factory_make ("theoradec",        "theora-decoder");
    audioConv    = gst_element_factory_make ("audioconvert",     "audio-converter");
    videoConv    = gst_element_factory_make ("ffmpegcolorspace", "video-converter");
    videosink    = gst_element_factory_make ("autovideosink",    "video-output");
    audiosink    = gst_element_factory_make ("autoaudiosink",    "audio-output");


    if (!pipeline || !source || !demuxer || !audioDecoder || !audioConv || !videoDecoder || !videoConv || !audioQueue 
            || !videoQueue || !audiosink || !videosink) {
        g_printerr ("One element could not be created. Exiting.\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    g_object_set (G_OBJECT (source), "location", argv[1], NULL);

    bus = gst_pipeline_get_bus (GST_PIPELINE (pipeline));
    gst_bus_add_watch (bus, bus_call, loop);
    gst_object_unref (bus);

    gst_bin_add_many (GST_BIN (pipeline),
                        source, demuxer, 
                        audioQueue, videoQueue, audioDecoder, videoDecoder,
                        videoConv, audioConv, videosink, audiosink, NULL);

    gst_element_link (source, demuxer);

    gst_element_link_many (videoQueue, videoDecoder, videoConv, videosink, NULL);
    g_signal_connect (demuxer, "pad-added", G_CALLBACK (on_pad_added), videoQueue);

    gst_element_link_many (audioQueue, audioDecoder, audioConv, audiosink, NULL);
    g_signal_connect (demuxer, "pad-added", G_CALLBACK (on_pad_added), audioQueue);

    g_print ("Lecture de : %s\n", argv[1]);
    gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);

    g_print ("En cours...\n");
    g_main_loop_run (loop);

    g_print ("Arret de la lecture\n");
    gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
    g_print ("Suppression du pipeline\n");
    gst_object_unref (GST_OBJECT (pipeline));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the pad-added callback (which you only need to connect to once!) you have to check the caps of the newly added pad.

Anyway, the video from the file would also need to be connected to subtitleoverlay, and you would link the video sink after subtitleoverlay. And you would link an additional filesrc for the subtitle file to subtitleoverlay too.

Take a look at the code inside playbin / playsink for subtitle handling, and especially for handling these things dynamically. Also note that playbin has a sub-uri property which allows you to select an external subtitle file that should be overlayed over the video.

Comment: I didn't get all of it, but I was looking for a solution without playbin if possible.

Comment: Which parts are not clear to you? :) Also why don't you want to use playbin, it's what we recommend for any playback use cases (except for super special ones, which yours doesn't seem to be).

Comment: I don't understand about the pad part. About playbin, it's because I was asked to make it work without it (otherwise I would use it with pleasure). I'm sorry for my lack of knowledge, but I just recently started working with gstreamer and the closest thing that I found was plain code without explanations.

Comment: I changed the command line, is this one better ? Can you please explain me what do you meant with what needed to be linked and how or a link to a tutorial ?

Comment: Yes, the new gst-launch pipeline you have there is correct. Alternatively you can also replace the subparse with the typefind element, in that case subtitleoverlay will select the appropriate elements for subtitle rendering based on the format itself. Also you can replace the demuxer and decoders with decodebin (or decodebin2 if you use GStreamer 0.10 as you seem to do... but use 1.x really).

Comment: And the way how you link the elements now is exactly what I meant, yes.

Comment: Sadly, I don't have the choice of the tools, so it have to be subparse, no playbin and this version of gstreamer.

Comment: And I still can't do the same in C, the best I have is this but it return an error on the data stream
    g_object_set (G_OBJECT (subSource), "location", argv[2], NULL);
    
    gst_element_link (videoConv, subOverlay);
    
    gst_element_link_many (subSource, subParse, NULL);
    g_signal_connect(subOverlay, "pad-added", G_CALLBACK (on_pad_added), subSource);

Comment: subparse has an ALWAYS pad, you can directly link it with gst_element_link_pads() for example. The pad-added signal on subparse will never be emitted as the pad exists from the moment you created the instance.
In your scenario you only need to use the pad-added signal for the demuxer.

You should also always check if linking elements succeeded or not, and if you get errors at runtime check the GStreamer debug logs for more information about what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much Sebastian Drödge, I can finally play the video with the subtitles. Here is the code I've done.

```
gst_element_link_many (videoQueue, videoDecoder, videoConv, subOverlay, videosink, NULL);
g_signal_connect (demuxer, "pad-added", G_CALLBACK (on_pad_added), videoQueue);

gst_element_link_many (audioQueue, audioDecoder, audioConv, audiosink, NULL);
g_signal_connect (demuxer, "pad-added", G_CALLBACK (on_pad_added), audioQueue);


g_object_set (G_OBJECT (subSource), "location", argv[2], NULL);
```

Now I'm thinking to use GTK to add features like pausing the video, it'll probably need to be cleaned a bit but that would do for now.