# Gstreamer launch with subtitles

Tags: gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

I am trying to play a video with gstreamer on my jetson nano with audio, video, and subtitles.

- The video does not play with `gst-play-1.0`
- The video plays with  `gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=ko.mkv ! decodebin name=decoder decoder. ! queue ! videoconvert ! autovideosink decoder. ! queue ! audioconvert ! autoaudiosink`
- I am unable to add a subtitle track here from a srt file

I tried the solution below but it does not work, in-fact any of the generic combinations for `gst-launch` in the tutorials don't really work except the one that I listed above.

Solution tried: [How to use gstreamer to overlay video with subtitles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39060494/how-to-use-gstreamer-to-overlay-video-with-subtitles)

Comment: Well if `gst-play-1.0` does not play it is probably due to some error. It may be that the subtitle track is broken?

Comment: `gst-play-1.0` is unable to play even without the subtitle track (the video has none). And the gst-launch example is also without.